# Two USB Cameras Causes USB Failure

Tags: usb, webcam

I've got two usb cameras that I run at one of two resolutions. They are USB 3 cameras running on the same USB 3.0 hub. If I run them at 1280x720 and 12 fps (about 23 MB/s of data) one camera will fail after about an hour, the second will continue indefinitely as far as I'm aware. If I run them at 640x480 at 30 fps (about 18.5 MB/s)  one camera tends to fail after about 24 hours, while the other will continue working. Either data rate is vastly within the spec for a usb 3.0, or even a usb 2.0 hub.

When a camera fails it is due the apparent failure of the usb port it is connected to. Nothing seems capable of reviving that port short of powering down the device, removing power, and starting it back up. A simple reboot does not solve the issue, I suspect this is because the usb ports do not power down unless power is removed from the computer.

Has anyone experienced anything like this, or have tips on how I can further debug this issue? I can update with more data but right now I'm not sure what data is useful.

Thanks.

Update1: Not sure of the significance, but I have confirmed my cameras are being read as USB 2.0 devices, not usb 3.0 devices:

```
$:~/locus_dev/src/locus_calibration$ lsusb -d 2560:c110 -v | grep USB
  bcdUSB               2.00
```

Update2: Contrary to my previous update i have found that some cameras are being read as usb 2.0 and some as 3.0 seemingly at random. Failure does not seem to be linked to 2.0 or 3.0 cameras. I checked the dmesg log around the time of a failure and found the text below. There were also references to killing processes due to 'Out Of Memory':

```
[14754.261924] uvcvideo: Non-zero status (-71) in video completion handler.
[14754.278012] uvcvideo: Non-zero status (-71) in video completion handler.
[14754.297514] uvcvideo: Non-zero status (-71) in video completion handler. [14754.311271] uvcvideo: Non-zero status (-71) in video completion handler.
[14754.402011] uvcvideo: Non-zero status (-71) in video completion handler.
[14760.459965] uvcvideo: Failed to query (130) UVC probe control : -110 (exp. 26).
[14775.656667] usb 3-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[14775.672307] usb 3-2: descriptor type invalid, skip
[14775.672311] usb 3-2: No LPM exit latency info found, disabling LPM.
[14775.672314] usb 3-2: device firmware changed
[14775.723768] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[14775.931744] usb 3-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[14775.948235] usb 3-2: no configurations
[14775.950077] usb 3-2: can't read configurations, error -22
[14776.143814] usb 3-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[14776.162902] usb 3-2: no configurations
[14776.164689] usb 3-2: can't read configurations, error -22
[14776.355745] usb 3-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[14776.372164] usb 3-2: no configurations
[14776.374073] usb 3-2: can't read configurations, error -22
[14776.567733] usb 3-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[14776.584193] usb 3-2: no configurations
[14776.586088] usb 3-2: can't read configurations, error -22
[14776.611732] usb usb3-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Comment: I would try them on separate hubs if possible to see if it is related to having them use one hub or not.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Unforunately this isn't an option as the hardware has only one exposed hub.